# Bridge Message: Asset not allowed

Tags: assets, bridge-server

```
May 17 15:48:02  bridge[20257]: time="2019-05-17T15:48:02+08:00" level=info msg="New received payment" id=1626714568404993 service=PaymentListener
May 17 15:48:02  bridge[20257]: time="2019-05-17T15:48:02+08:00" level=info msg="Asset not allowed" service=PaymentListener

I use api.someone.io/builder 
operations[
  set_option,
  change trust,
  allow trust,
  payment
]
```

I got 'Asset not allowed' from bridge, can anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set allowed assets in the [config file](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/bridge/README.md#config): `assets` field.